How to solve this limit $\lim_{n\to \infty } \sum_{k=0}^n 1/[(2k+1)(2k+3)]$
Help please:
$$
\mbox{I tried to do it like this}\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over \left(2k + 1\right)\left(2k + 3\right)}$$
but I don't know how to continue.

Do telescopic summation of the series then take limit.

Questions like this a essentially duplicates.

Hint: $\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+3}=\frac{2}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}$

Thank you! Does this seem correct?
$\lim_{n\to \infty } \sum_{k=0}^n\ 1/2 *\frac{2}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}$=
$\lim_{n\to \infty } 1/2 * \sum_{k=0}^n(\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+3})$
= $\lim_{n\to \infty } 1/2 *(1 - 1/3 + 1/3 - 1/5 +1/5 - 1/7 + ... + 1/(2n+1) - 1/(2n+3))$
= $\lim_{n\to \infty } 1/2 * (1-\frac{1}{2n+3})$ = 1/2

@intenziven: yes, that's correct!
